# Why does float setting not working? Is it because of li or ul?

Tags: html, css

I am making auto-carousel, but `li` floating doesn't work. Why does the list stretch horizontally? If I set `display: block;` or `overflow: hidden;` to `ul`, it just cuts the bottom part and does not float the list.

**HTML and CSS**

```css
    ul.slide-wrap {
        position: relative;
        width: 600%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .slide-box {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    li.slide-item {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="slide-box">
        <ul class="slide-wrap">
            <li class="slide-item">1</li>
            <li class="slide-item">2</li>
            <li class="slide-item">3</li>
            <li class="slide-item">4</li>
            <li class="slide-item">5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle link and share it here?

Your question is unclear on what is it you want to do....

Comment: @Abhishek Jain https://jsfiddle.net/osbkeaq7/ here's jsfiddle, and I want to make the list floating left for auto-slideshow. However it just aligned vertically...

Comment: Because the `li` are 100% wide, remove that!

Answer (score 0):

I did this, I didn't resolve it but here you have some tips:

```
ul.slide-wrap {
    /* position: relative; */
    width: 600%;
    /* height: 100%; */
    /* you can use height: 100vh; */
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.slide-box {
    /* position: absolute; */
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100%; */
    z-index: 1;
}
li.slide-item {
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100%; */
    /* float: left; */
}
```

And you can set this to the body to ensure you don't pass 100% width so you don't have that horizontal scroll:

```
body {
    max-width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I just tried but still list does not float..

Comment: and yea, height: 100% i think doesn't really work, i'd use 100vh. Check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window